# How can I get indices of the first column from a 2-D array that satisfies the condition without Iterations?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Assuming X like this:

```
[[6 3 4]
 [3 0 9]
 [7 7 8]
 [8 5 1]
 [8 3 8]]
```

the condition   `x < 5`

and then get array like this, they are the indices of the first column in the array that satisfies the condition.

```
[1,0,None,2,1]
```

can I get result like this without  iterations in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost `np.argmax` with a mask but since `argmax` will return 0 when all elements of a row are `False` in a mask, we can resort to `any`. Also, to incorporate `None`, integer type isn't enough:

```
# get a boolean array over the condition
mask = x < 5

# argmax and any over rows of the mask
idx_max = mask.argmax(axis=1).astype(float)
any_okay = mask.any(axis=1)

# put None to rows where there is not (~) any entry that satisfied the condition
idx_max[~any_okay] = np.nan
```

to get

```
>>> idx_max

array([ 1.,  0., nan,  2.,  1.])
```